# Arriving to the integral of $\sec(x)$

Tags: calculus

So I was looking at how to obtain the following integral $$\int \sec(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ I saw that, to solve it, they divided and multiplied by $\tan(x)sec(x)/tan(x)sec(x)$. I understand that this is the equivalent to multiplying by $1$ and that they can do this. However, I would like to understand the *logic behind why* they are multiplying by this instead of some other trig ratio? Also is there any other way to solve this integral? I looked around but the only result I could find was multiplying and dividing by $\tan(x)sec(x)/tan(x)sec(x)$

Comment: the logic behind it is finding it's antiderivative.

Comment: it is $\sect+\tan t$.

Comment: Using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution will be more natural way

Comment: So they just plugged and chugged until they arrived to the antiderivative, or? @Nosrati

Comment: Notice that the integrand is $\dfrac{\sec x \tan x + \sec^{2}x }{\sec x+ \tan x }$ so that you can pull it to a logarithmic form.

Answer (score 3):

There is some interesting history behind this. A formula for the integral (which is needed for construction of Mercator's projection maps) was discovered in a numerical comparison of two tables of numbers, and published in 1645.  To prove it was an important open problem in the mid-17th century. James Gregory found a very complicated proof in 1668, and Barrow a simpler one in 1670. All this was before the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: once you have that, it's completely elementary to verify by differentiating. See e.g. [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m103/mercator/mercator.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another way
\begin{align}
\int\dfrac{1}{\cos x}dx
&= \int\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}dx \\
&= \dfrac12\int\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}dx+\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}dx \\
&= \dfrac12\ln\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways other than multiplying by $\dfrac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}$.

For example, you could use the Weierstrass $t$-substitution
$$
\begin{align*}
\tan\frac{x}{2}&=t\\
\cos x&=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\
\sin x&=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\\
\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}
\end{align*}
$$
which convert a rational function of trigonometric functions of $x$ to a rational function of $t$, from which there are standard procedure you can follow to find its antiderivative (partial fractions and the worst case involves integrating $\dfrac{a+bu}{(1+u^2)^m}$).  So
$$
\int\sec x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}\,\frac{2\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}=\int\left(\frac1{t-1}-\frac1{t+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
which you can integrate immediately.